# Good practices for managing activity load time

Tags: java, android, android-activity, oncreate

I have been reading lot of answers to get this solved, but somehow I didn't get a proper solution. I am a beginer and may be for that reason.

I am creating a new activity B on a button click on activity A. B has lot of UI. So it takes around 10 seconds to load. It shows a black screen till.

```
public class B extends Activity
{


    Dialog dialog_sec1__participant_name;
    Dialog dialog_sec1__fathers_name;
    Dialog dialog_sec1_address;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    //lot more
    Button btn_section_preview;
    Button btn_sec1_address;
    .
    .
    //lot more


    CustomObj mObject = null;
    CustomObj2 mObject2 = null;
    .
    .
    .



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.B);

    mObject = new CustomObj();
    mObject2 = new CustomObj();
    .
    .



    txt_sec1_preview_household_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.a11);
    txt_sec1_preview_date_of_interview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.a22);
    txt_sec1_preview_time_of_interview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.a33);
    .
    .
    .
    // Lot more, including setting view to Dialog.

    .
    .
    .
    // and lot of onclick listners

      btn_section_preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
          {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                //doing my job here
            }
        });
         .
         .
         .
         .
```

There are lot of UI components in this view. My current structure is like this. Now ,

1. How I can reduce the load time?
2. What is a good method ( practise ) to do , if the above way is not
   a good way .

Please guide me.

Comment: i think your image file dimension is bigger than layout , check your drawable folder images , it may take time to load your activity.

Comment: @Anand No.. it isn't the problem. Actually I have ~ 200 + UI elements and listeners. I am looking for a good practice to handle this

Comment: k..did you try to launch again

Answer (score 1):

If you have about 200 elements that arranges from top to bottom you could try to use ListView, it will handle lazy loading for you. So in starting an activity you will load only visible elements. Or try to use another method to implement lazy loading, look at ViewStub for example. So the main idea here is to divide your layout and allow it to load partially.

Comment: I can't use list view here. It isn't a top - bottom like. I think , i need to do some partial loading. But dont know how to do

Comment: May be fragments and ViewPager or another tab layout could help you. Or with ViewStub you could make expandable layout

Comment: This is a good answer. If it isn't a top to bottom thing like you said, then can we see a quick mockup or explanation of how this is laid out? Otherwise it's tough to offer the right suggestion. Otherwise, maybe a GridView will help you lay it out a little differently than a ListView. Honestly though, it sounds like you really just need to split this into multiple Activities or into a ViewPager + Fragments if it isn't any kind of list or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a progress bar until your UI load. You should also read [best practice](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html) to optimize layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is taking 10 seconds to load, you must be hitting the ANR limit in some cases (http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Without detailed information about your UI, I can only speculate and offer some general tips:

- Don't initialize all your Dialogs at once. Why are you even initializing every dialog? Why do you even need multiple instances of dialogs? Why not just wait until a dialog is triggered before creating the associated object? And why not just maintain a reference to the current/last one displayed as opposed to all of them?
- You say you have a lot of OnClickListeners. Make sure you use a single OnClickListener object and simply pass the reference to multiple views. This way you only create one object as opposed to multiple which can be a performance hit.
- Anything you do in onCreate() slows down the Activity's startup, so limit the work you do there. If it's not needed at the start, then initialize it later!
- At all costs, avoid blocking calls in onCreate() / the UI thread. That is, any network calls or database calls. Based on your example, you seem to be fine... but with a delay of 10 seconds, one has to assume you made a blocking call in your onCreate() call (or maybe the onStart()/onResume() ?). If you need one, use an AsyncTask/Thread.

For supporting docs, take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation (Object Creation is never free!)
In addition, I know it was already recommended, but layout optimization is very important if your UI is complex: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html

Hope that helps! Good luck